Error while train model locally 'The attention mask and the pad token id were not set. `attention_mask` .Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id'
When i Running model - srimanth-d/GOT_CPU locally I get Following Error:
The attention mask and the pad token id were not set. As a consequence, you may observe unexpected behavior. Please pass your input'sattention_maskto obtain reliable results. Settingpad_token_idtoeos_token_id:None for open-end generation. The attention mask is not set and cannot be inferred from input because pad token is same as eos token. As a consequence, you may observe unexpected behavior. Please pass your input's attention_maskto obtain reliable results. Theseen_tokensattribute is deprecated and will be removed in v4.41. Use thecache_positionmodel input instead.
The Code Which i Run Locally is Following -
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('srimanth-d/GOT_CPU', trust_remote_code=True)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('srimanth-d/GOT_CPU', trust_remote_code=True, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, use_safetensors=True, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
model = model.eval()


image_file = 'images.png'


res = model.chat(tokenizer, image_file, ocr_type='ocr')

print(res)

Help me to fixed these problem.
I have try various methods like manually passing the token. But they did not work.
